# iOS 7 - Is it possible to implement gradient scale on UISlider?

Tags: ios, ios7, scale, gradient, uislider

I would like to implement an UISlider with the acceptable value of 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, and 30. Basically, I want the UISlider with a finer scale at the lower score, and more coarse scale at the higher score. One of my idea is to programmatically round off of the float value from UISlider. However, I want to know if there might be a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the min and max of the UISlider, let's say 1-10.  In the code, every time the value of the slider changes, add a switch statement where you have a case for each number from 1-10 and you can set 15, 20, 30, whatever number you want.